# Trigger mousewheel event with touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, mousewheel

I have a event bind to mousewheel in which I use the event to make some calculations, I would like to be able to use the same function to perform the same calculations from touch devices.

my code is like:

```
$('#element').bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0)
                //do stuff
            else {
               //do other stuff
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:** As from the comment I understand i was not completely clear, my goal is to obtain a value like "**wheelDelta**" that make me recognize if the user is scrolling (touchmoving) up or down

Comment: There is no `mousewheel` event for touch devices. Maybe you should try using `mousemove` and `touchmove` together?

Comment: You can try my plugin [jquery-do-scroll](https://github.com/WashingtonGuedes/jquery-do-scroll). It works with mouse, touch, and wheel events.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the appropriate solution but you may do something like this.

```
  var lastScroll = 0;

  $('#element').on("scroll", function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScroll){
       // downscroll code
       //$(this).trigger("mousewheeldown");
    } else {
      // upscroll code
      //$(this).trigger("mousewheelup");
    }
    lastScroll = st;
    $(this).trigger("mousewheel");
  });
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Why would they do something like this?

Comment: He can basically detect one user generated event and manually trigger another. That's basically what he wants as per my understanding.

Comment: There's no click on my code I do not understand why I would try something like what you suggested

Comment: okay. I guess you need to listen for scroll event instead of click and trigger mousewheel instead of scroll.

Comment: I need to know the direction of the scroll

Comment: I have updated the answer to detect scroll direction.